# Swift : WKWebView not showing image on device

Tags: swift

I am loading a html file to WKWebview from local everything is working fine but it is not showing image on iPhone.

This is the code i am using to load a html file

```
 do{
        let fileName =  try String(contentsOf: destinationURLForFile)
        print("fileName is equal to\(fileName)")
        webView.loadHTMLString(fileName, baseURL: destinationURLForFile)


    }catch{

    }
```

Trying to fix since hours. Any suggestions would be helpful!

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar issue yesterday, you need to tell the build to copy this file to the device as part of the bundle.

Make sure sure you have the HTML file in the Copy Bundle Resources part of the build settings. Just go to the project settings > build phases > copy bundle resources and if your HTML file is not listed there, click the + button and add it.

This should solve your issue, if not could you please provide more information, are you getting any errors, does the file actually exist?

Comment: But my files are in local folder(document directory) i have to move it?

Comment: When you add a random file to an xcode project, it does not automatically become part of what is copied to the device during install. You need to follow the instructions in my answer to check that xcode knows that you want this file copied to the device. you do not need to move it at all. Imagine all the other files you could have in a project.. readme files, configuration files for automated builds (swiftlint.yml for example). these aren't needed in the project, so xcode wont copy them.